# Woocommerce Custom Navigation Menu for Specific Products

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, woocommerce, nav

I am using Woocommerce plugin for my online services(not physical products)
Just one of my service's page here:
http://www.vaservicesph.com/product/whiteboard-animation-service-basic/

I'm also using Optimizepress theme on the site.

Here's what optimizepress have on header section(it's using the blog template for the woocommerce stuffs):

**a. An option to add a nav menu at the top**

**b. An option to add a nav menu alongside the logo**

Here's a screenshot of option -> screencast.com/t/zsrlLec9CH

And they will be located here on the page: -> screencast.com/t/djtqjaZZ5

*Please add http on my screencast links if it'll not work(sorry about this, I'm new to stackoverflow and need more points to post more links).

So if I enable a menu for my blog, they will appear on the top(alongside logo) and will also be used for my product page template(which is not good).

What I'd like to do is use a different menu for these specific service only. So whiteboard services will only have nav menus about whiteboard services related pages(that I specify).

How can I do this? Hope I'm clear to my question. Thank you!

--
Clint

Answer (score 0):

You could register a second menu in your functions.php:

```
register_nav_menu( 'product', 'Product Menu' );
```

And then wherever you are displaying the main menu (possibly header.php) you can adjust it to use conditional logic to display the product menu in one case and your theme's primary menu in all others. For example:

```
if( function_exists('is_product') && is_product() ){
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'product' ) );
} else {
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
}
```

This isn't meant to be a complete answer, but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction. You can use any kind of conditional logic that you'd like.  Checking product categories might be a good idea if you put all your whiteboard products in the same category.

Comment: Thanks for your response helgatheviking. I can understand what your code can accomplish but due to my lack of knowledge regarding the theme and woocommerce' template, it's hard for me to integrate it. I don't know which particular part of the template should I add, remove and replace :-). haha!

Anyways, I have found a solution which I think a bit of childish way. I will post it that it might help others who got the same issue. :-)

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, this code is destined for header.php. Though you could also copy `header.php` over to `header-shop.php` which WooCommerce calls. If this is the only difference between headers, I think it is simpler to wrap the menu code in an IF/ELSE statement. What part are you struggling with?

Comment: Well, here's the entire code of the blog header.php template(that is being fetched by woocommerce) of the theme which I'm confused how to insert the conditional stuffs.

http://pastebin.com/vAimW3h4

Can you show me an example how can I achieve it on that template page?

Comment: Well your theme is over-complicated, that's for sure. Here's my best guess: http://pastebin.com/TsDuZW5f atleast for the bottom nav. What that is wrapped in an extra `<ul>` I have no idea. And what is going on with the sidenav I can't tell either.

Answer (score 0):

I spent couple of hours to figure this out. I know code experts might find this to be a childish solution, but it is what I found due to my lack of knowledge of coding. So here's what I did:

1. First, I registered a new menu called "Whiteboard Animation Service" with slug 'whiteboard_menu' using the code below:

   // Adding Whiteboard Nav Menus
   function register_whiteboard_menu() {
       register_nav_menu( 'whiteboard_menu', 'Whiteboard Service Menu' );
   }

   add_action( 'init', 'register_whiteboard_menu' );
2. Next After that, I created a new header template and call it **header-whiteboard-cfe.php** on my child theme.
3. And then I copied the original header.php content(the entire codes - used by my blog template) and pasted it on the my new created header(header-whiteboard-cfe.php). Then I replaced all the 'primary' slugs I found on that template(use Find and Replace)to my new registered menu slug 'whiteboard-menu'.
4. I called the header on my "single-product.php' of my woocommerce template. I replaced the get_header('shop') with get_header('header-whiteboard-cfe.php').
5. I already have the menus setup on the Menu section of wordpress(called it "Whiteboard Service"). Then I selected the Whiteboard Service Menu as the location.

Then viola! Got it displayed on my single product page for my whiteboard services! So if I have to display a different menu for different services, then I just have to do these process.

Do you have any other ideas or other solution you could suggest? Would love to hear yours. Thank you!!